# Cannot get warpPerspective to get correct transformation

Tags: java, android, opencv, image-processing, perspective

Already tried all the options found on the net.
The coordinates are correct. The order is equal on vectors.
[image: Before and after]
What am I missing?

```
public void cropBtn(View view) {
    List<Point> corners=new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i=0;i<4;i++)
        corners.add(new Point(cropPanel.corners[i].x,cropPanel.corners[i].y));


    List<Point> target=new ArrayList<>();
    target.add(new Point(cropPanel.left,cropPanel.top));
    target.add(new Point(cropPanel.right,cropPanel.top));
    target.add(new Point(cropPanel.right,cropPanel.bottom));
    target.add(new Point(cropPanel.left,cropPanel.bottom));

    Mat trans=Imgproc.getPerspectiveTransform(Converters.vector_Point2f_to_Mat(corners), Converters.vector_Point2f_to_Mat(target));

    Mat src = new Mat(bitmap.getHeight(), bitmap.getWidth(), CvType.CV_8SC1);
    Utils.bitmapToMat(bitmap, src);
    Mat dst = new Mat(bitmap.getHeight(), bitmap.getWidth(), CvType.CV_8SC1);
    Imgproc.warpPerspective(src, dst, trans, dst.size());

    Utils.matToBitmap(dst, bitmap);
    image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    cropPanel.reset();
}
```

Comment: Can you print out the coordinates of the points in `target` and `corners` in this scenario and add them to the question?

Comment: in c++ openCV there is aometimes some ambiguity when converting small point lists to Mats. Is there no api in java where you can provide the points directly as Lists instead of converting to Mat?

Comment: Coords for example:
Bitmap/View size (924,1353)
corners({382,483},{858,578},{656,1292},{101,1152})
target ({60,60},{864,60},{864,1293},{60,1293})

Answer (score 0):

I think, you are getting wrong points. So , i would suggest to try below code:

```
 MatOfPoint2f thisContour2f = new MatOfPoint2f();
        MatOfPoint2f approxContour2f = new MatOfPoint2f();

    contours.get(maxI).convertTo(thisContour2f, CvType.CV_32FC2); // here contours is a List of MatOfPoint which you get from ImgProc.findContours() method.
    Imgproc.approxPolyDP(thisContour2f, approxContour2f, Imgproc.arcLength(thisContour2f, true) * 0.01, true); // Approximates a polygonal curve(s) with the specified precision. since you have to detect document which is rectangle , you need to find four points

    if (approxContour2f.size().height == 4) { // since we are detecting rectangle , check wether contours has 4 points

    MatOfPoint2f rotatedMat = new MatOfPoint2f(contours.get(maxI).toArray());
            RotatedRect boundingBox = Imgproc.minAreaRect(rotatedMat);  // find RotatedRect from contours 

        double[] temp_double;                       // find four points
                    temp_double = approxContour2f.get(0, 0);
                    Point p1 = new Point(temp_double[0], temp_double[1]);

                    temp_double = approxContour2f.get(1, 0);
                    Point p2 = new Point(temp_double[0], temp_double[1]);

                    temp_double = approxContour2f.get(2, 0);
                    Point p3 = new Point(temp_double[0], temp_double[1]);

                    temp_double = approxContour2f.get(3, 0);
                    Point p4 = new Point(temp_double[0], temp_double[1]);

        List<Point> source = new ArrayList<>();
                    source.add(p1);
                    source.add(p2);
                    source.add(p3);
                    source.add(p4);

        Mat startM = Converters.vector_Point2f_to_Mat(source);        
`       Mat result = warp(mRgba, startM, boundingBox.boundingRect());  // mrgba is a original mat

     }
```

Now , you can perspect it from below warp() function :

```
public Mat warp(Mat inputMat, Mat startM, Rect rect) {

    int resultWidth = rect.width;
    int resultHeight = rect.height;

    Point ocvPOut4, ocvPOut1, ocvPOut2, ocvPOut3;

    ocvPOut1 = new Point(0, 0);
            ocvPOut2 = new Point(0, resultHeight);
            ocvPOut3 = new Point(resultWidth, resultHeight);
            ocvPOut4 = new Point(resultWidth, 0);

    Mat outputMat = new Mat(resultWidth, resultHeight, CvType.CV_8UC4);

    List<Point> dest = new ArrayList<Point>();
    dest.add(ocvPOut1);
    dest.add(ocvPOut2);
    dest.add(ocvPOut3);
    dest.add(ocvPOut4);
    Mat endM = Converters.vector_Point2f_to_Mat(dest);

    Mat perspectiveTransform = Imgproc.getPerspectiveTransform(startM, endM);

    Imgproc.warpPerspective(inputMat, outputMat, perspectiveTransform, new Size(resultWidth, resultHeight), Imgproc.INTER_CUBIC);

    return outputMat;
}
```

hope it will help !!

Answer (score -1):

After a lot of hours of fight with that, finally found the problem.

Just post here. Maybe help to someone in my situation.

The problem was: I used coordinates of the view. And need the coordinates of bitmap. That maked the warp completely crazy behaviour. So just translated from View's coords to Bitmaps's. Now it's perfect:

```
float xRatio=(float)bitmap.getWidth()/cropPanel.getWidth();
float yRatio=(float)bitmap.getHeight()/cropPanel.getHeight();

for (int i=0;i<4;i++)
    corners.add(new Point(cropPanel.corners[i].x*xRatio,cropPanel.corners[i].y*yRatio);

List<Point> target=new ArrayList<>();
target.add(new Point(0,0));
target.add(new Point(bitmap.getWidth(),0));
target.add(new Point(bitmap.getWidth(),bitmap.getHeight()));
target.add(new Point(0,bitmap.getHeight()));
```